# O que é JRD em engenharia de software?

Tags: engenharia-de-software

O que são Sessões de Desenvolvimento de Requisitos Conjuntos (JRD)? Sei que fazem parte da engenharia do software, mas não entendi essa parte:

> Os requisitos geralmente têm implicações interfuncionais desconhecidas
>   para as partes interessadas individuais e muitas vezes perdidas ou
>   incompletamente definidas durante as entrevistas com as partes
>   interessadas. Essas implicações multifuncionais podem ser obtidas
>   através da realização de sessões de JRD em um ambiente controlado,
>   facilitado por um facilitador treinado (analista de negócios), no qual
>   as partes interessadas participam de discussões para obter requisitos,
>   analisam seus detalhes e descobrem implicações interfuncionais. Um
>   escriba dedicado deve estar presente para documentar a discussão,
>   liberando o Analista de Negócios para liderar a discussão em uma
>   direção que gere requisitos apropriados que atendam ao objetivo da
>   sessão.
>
> As sessões JRD são análogas às sessões de design de aplicativos
>   conjuntos . No primeiro, as sessões eliciam requisitos que orientam o
>   design, enquanto o segundo elicita os recursos específicos do design a
>   serem implementados de acordo com os requisitos elicitados.

Fonte: [Wikipedia (inglês)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requirements_analysis#Joint_Requirements_Development_(JRD)_Sessions)

Answer (score 0):

O processo de identificação e análise de requisitos envolve diversos stakeholders - pessoas e organizações interessadas ou afetadas pelo sistema em desenvolvimento.

Um desafio recorrente em projetos é lidar com conflitos entre as visões que os stakeholders têm do sistema e do que ele deve fazer. Apenas como ilustração, em um sistema de gestão de transporte, uma solicitação de um stakeholder A para que o sistema exiba um mapa com a posição atual dos veículos com precisão mínima de 5 metros pode conflitar com a solicitação de outro stakeholder B que estabeleceu um limite para o preço dos GPSs a serem comprados, que poderão resultar em medições de precisão inferior.

Neste contexto, as JRD são sessões conduzidas com a presença de stakeholders de diferentes áreas e com diferentes visões, visando identificar possíveis conflitos, contradições, impactos e efeitos nos requisitos - que não seriam percebidos caso a análise fosse feita sob a ótica de apenas um ou de um grupo pequeno de stakeholders.